# How to prove that a derivative of a formula equals to another formula.

Tags: calculus, integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

If $u= \ln(\tan x+\tan y+\tan z)$ prove $$\sin 2x \dfrac{du}{dx} + \sin 2y  \dfrac{du}{dy} + \sin 2z   \dfrac{du}{dz}=2 $$

My answwer was like this:
$$u' =\dfrac{ 1}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z} \cdot( \sec^2 x +\sec^2 y +\sec^2 z )$$

$$   =\dfrac{ 1}{\dfrac{\sin x}{\cos x} + \dfrac{\sin y}{\cos y} + \dfrac{\sin z}{\cos z}}\cdot(\sec^2x + \sec^2y + \sec^2z)$$

$$  =\dfrac{ \cos x+\cos y+\cos z}{\sin x+\sin y+\sin z}\cdot(\sec^2x + \sec^2y + \sec^2z)$$

$$   = \sin 2x (\dfrac{\cos x}{\sin x})+ \sin 2y (\dfrac{\cos y}{\sin y}) + \sin 2z (\dfrac{\cos z}{\sin z})\cdot( \sec^2 x +\sec^2 y +\sec^2 z )$$

$$   =\dfrac{ 2\sin x\cos x}{\sin x} +\dfrac{ 2\sin y \cos y}{\sin x} +\dfrac{ 2\sin z\cos z}{\sin z}\cdot(\sec^2x + \sec^2y + \sec^2z)$$

$$=\dfrac{ \sin 2x}{\sin x} + \dfrac{ \sin 2y}{\sin x} + \dfrac{ \sin 2z}{\sin z}\cdot(\sec^2x + \sec^2y + \sec^2z)$$

I solved until here and I got stuck. Is my answer right until now? How could I finish it to prove that it equals to 2? Sorry for the wrong codes.

Comment: can anybody help me to edit the codes pleas

Comment: What's "in(...)"?

Comment: @MPW it means integration In

Comment: I edited the source to try to improve the formatting. But the opening integral notation doesn't make sense. It's not clear with respect to what variable the integration is being performed.

Comment: @MPW sorry its not integration its ln and thanks for the edit

Comment: What is $u'$ supposed to signify in the first line? You're definitely missing the relevant applications of the chain rule.

Comment: @Semiclassical what about now, there was something wrong with the coding

Comment: and tnx to @MPW for editing the code again :)

Comment: You'll have to edit it further, I'm not certain I have translated it to what you meant, my apologies. The last three lines of math look very suspicious, please correct it.

Comment: this is my finale edit @MPW tnx again , and i hope it makes since now

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you should just compute the relevant partials and then verify that LHS $=$ RHS.

Something like:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{\tan x + \tan y + \tan z} \cdot \sec^2x \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{\tan x + \tan y + \tan z} \cdot \sec^2y \\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z} = \frac{1}{\tan x + \tan y + \tan z} \cdot \sec^2z \\$$

The LHS then becomes

$$\frac{\sin(2x)\sec^2x + \sin(2y)\sec^2y+ \sin(2z)\sec^2z}{\tan x + \tan y + \tan z} = 2\left(\frac{ \tan x + \tan y + \tan z}{\tan x + \tan y + \tan z}\right) = 2$$

Which clearly equals the RHS.

Comment: thank for the answer , i have one question . how does sin(2x)sec^2x is equal to tanx ? is there a rule for that

Comment: @AhmdinhoMufasa: It's equivalent to the double-angle formula for sine.

Answer (score 0):

We have that

$$u(x,y,z)=\ln(\tan x+\tan y+\tan z)$$

Then

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}=\frac{\sec^2x}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}=\frac{\sec^2y}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}\\
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\frac{\sec^2z}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}$$

Then

$$\sin(2x)\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}+\sin(2y)\frac{\partial u}{\partial y}+\sin(2z)\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=\\
\frac{\sin(2x)\sec^2x+\sin(2y)\sec^2y+\sin(2z)\sec^2z}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}=\\
\frac{2\sin x\cos x\sec^2x+2\sin y\cos y\sec^2y+2\sin z\cos z\sec^2z}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}=\\
2\frac{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}{\tan x+\tan y+\tan z}=2$$

Comment: thanks for the answer :) it helped alot , i have one question . how does sin(2x)sec^2x is equal to tanx ? is there a rule for that

Comment: Its equal to $2\tan x$, its comes from double angle formula for sine and $\sec x=\frac{1}{\cos x}$ and $\tan x=\frac{\sin x}{\cos x}$